# Issues with SQL Linq expression in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to do the following but have an error that a ) is expected. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var q = from kvp2 in entityToCluster
        join kvp3 in clusterToQVR on kvp2.Value equals kvp3.Key
        where kvp2.key equals entity1 or kvp2.key equals entity2
        select new {entity = kvp2.Key, cluster = kvp2.Value, qvRule = kvp3.Value};
```

If I change the query to this possible solution, I get a different error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.key' is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
var q = from kvp2 in entityToCluster
        join kvp3 in clusterToQVR on kvp2.Value equals kvp3.Key
        where kvp2.key == entity1 || kvp2.key == entity2
        select new {entity = kvp2.Key, cluster = kvp2.Value, qvRule = kvp3.Value};
```

Comment: Sorry what is the error in the first line?

Comment: I'm wondering what makes you type `kvp2.key` (lower case) after you typed `kvp3.Key`.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a private member of the dictionary so use `Key` with the capital letter will solve the problem

```
where kvp2.Key equals entity1 or kvp2.Key equals entity2
```